# select OutputFormatter depending on the query parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I need to select `OutputFormatter` depending on the query parameter. How to do that?
I am moving from `.NET Framework WebApi` to `.NET Core WebApi.` The `.NET Framework WebApi` had `DefaultContentNegotiator` class do that:

```
public class CustomContentNegotiator : DefaultContentNegotiator
{
        
    
    public override ContentNegotiationResult Negotiate(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters)
        {       
                //Read query from request object and add output formatters below
                bindFormatters = new List<MediaTypeFormatter>
                {
                    new ConvertResultRawFormatter(),
                    new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
                    {
                        SerializerSettings =
                        {
                            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
    
            return base.Negotiate(type, request, bindFormatters);
        }
}
```

replace in configuration with new formatted negotiator

```
 config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new CustomContentNegotiator());
```

Comment: Have you checked the [Custom formatters in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-6.0) document?

Comment: Why are you trying to modify the content negotiator instead of registering a new formatter for the content type you want?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, it does not show how to select formatters depending on query, only by MediaTypes

Comment: That's the standard way. Anything else is custom application coding.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As I explained in my question I need to select formatted by query and not by content type,

Comment: The question contains a lot of code but nothing says `I want to change the response content type based on a query parameter` or `route parameter`. I'm sure there are samples that show how to do either, but that's custom coding, not the standard HTTP way. You'd still have to register the formatters

Comment: Found it: [Response format URL mappingss](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#response-format-url-mappings)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand that this requirement is not a standard approach but still I need to move my Web API to the core without breaking functionality.

Comment: I posted the link to how that can be done through route parameters. The link shows that once you add the `FormatFilter` attribute to a controller, the format will be specified by the route's `{format}` parameter

Comment: You still haven't explained how you want to specify the format. It may be possible to specify the `{format}` part in the default routes and have it used in any controller marked with `[FormatFilter]`. The attribute itself instructs the runtime to use the [FormatFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.formatfilter?view=aspnetcore-6.0) filter. You could add this explicitly in the `AddControllers` configuration for all controllers

Comment: I need to siwtch to custom OutputFormatter if request has "download=inline" query parameter. I do not see how FormatFilter could help me in this situation.

Comment: That's a Content-Disposition value, not a format. Is the *real* request to add `Content-Disposition: inline` to the response if `download=inline` is a query parameter? Using a formatter for this was wrong from the start. That's something that should be handled by filters, the way `FormatFilter` works. If the request has this query parameter, include `Content-Disposition: inline` in the response

Comment: You could check the [FormatFilter](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Formatters/FormatFilter.cs) implementation, although the code in your case would be a *lot* simpler. In `OnResourceExecuting` check `RouteData` for the `download` parameter. In `OnResultExecuting` you can add the header with `context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add`.

Comment: You could also add an [inline middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-class) delegate in Program.cs that adds the Response header if the Request.Query contains a `download` key with the value you want

Answer (score 0):

Will the custom output formatters not work for you?  Read this [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it seems that the *real* question is how to add the `Content-Disposition: inline` header if the URL contains `download=inline` parameter. This doesn't concern formatting or content negotiation.

There are several ways to add headers to a response. One of them is to add inline middleware that adds the header if the query parameter is present :

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => 
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(() => 
    {
        var download= context.Request.Query["download"];
        if (download=="inline")
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline");
        }
    }
}
```

This affects all routes